# How to write a macro which looks at a specific value then copies and pastes it to a specific location on another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to writing VBA and I have had some trouble writing a code. I have searched through all the different questions people have asked with similar issues to mine and although there has been very similar questions asked I cannot find a way of applying them to my problem.
I am creating a schedule based on a list of priorities. On one worksheet "Organisation Tab 2" I have assigned a rank number to each operation which needs scheduling. There are 35 ranks assigned.

I want the macro to look at the rank column (E) in "CMM schedule" and when it finds a specific value look at the "Organisation Tab 2" worksheet and copy and paste the cells of the rank value found at the location it finds the rank value in the "CMM schedule". E.g. If rank (column E) in "CMM schedule" is 5 then copy and paste the rows from rank 5 "Organisation Tab 2" worksheet at the location of where the value 5 was found in the "CMM schedule".

I hope this makes sense and appreciate somebodies help.

Comment: SO isn't a pre-code distributor, 1th you can try to use a macro recorder to create one macro to do want you want to do (in your post isn't clear) after you can post here your macro and we can help you to create one function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use VBA code. A formula such as:

```
=INDIRECT("A" & MATCH(RANK(D9,B:B,-1),B:B,FALSE))
```

will work. If you want to use VBA code a simple function is needed.

What route do you want to use?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried implementing this formula but couldn't get it to work. Could you provide the macro alternative please?